# New "Shortcut" for Apache2 content

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a new folder under `/var/www`, let's call it "MyApp".

Its starting point is index.php

I'd like that externally, anyone who URLs to `http://my_machine/MyApp` will get the contents of my index.php.

Where in Apache2 to I configure that?

btw: phpMyAdmin does the same I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just create a new folder `/var/www/MyApp`. The URL `http://my_machine/MyApp` will be forwarded to the index.php page there.

If you want to forward it to another path, you can `Alias` attribute in apache config.